# How do I resolve global is not defined issue using Cognito and Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a Vue3 app that I want to integrate Cognito into with a custom login page. I am attempting to use aws-amplify although am open to other recommendations.

I am calling Amplify.configure in my main.ts just prior to calling createApp and have also tried doing the same in App.vue. In either case I get the following error

'Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined at node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43:30)'

Based on my investigation, it looks like this is due to a change in how vue works. The remediations seem to be based on defining global explicitly in code, however these don't seem to be working here.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else comes to this who is struggling here, vite (the no bundler dev environment used by Vue) allows you to define runtime variables to be made available in the code (details here: [Configuring Vite](https://vitejs.dev/config/#:%7E:text=Vite%20also%20directly%20supports%20TS%20config%20files.%20You,build%20%28ssrBuild%29%2C%20it%20can%20export%20a%20function%20instead%3A)). In this case, it is actually enough to define global as an empty object as below:

```
define: {
  global: {},
}
```